How to create a relationship between two tables while joining to another table in sqlalchemy?
I am trying to create sqlalchemy relationship between two tables which relies on a value of another table. My UserSports table has a relationship with the Baseball table (as well as other sports that they may have played). I also have a Sports enums table which joins to the Users table. The goal is to create a relationship between UserSports and Baseball using Sports enums.  user_sports.id and baseball.user_sport_id is a one-to-one relationship. The sql would be something like:
SELECT *
FROM user_sports us
JOIN sports       s ON s.id            = us.sport_id
                   AND s.sport         = 'baseball'
JOIN baseball     b ON b.user_sport_id = us.id

class UserSports(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_sports"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    sport_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('states.id', nullable=False)
    sports: Mapped['Sports'] = relationship(back_populates='user_sports', foreign_keys=[sport_id])
     baseball: Mapped['Baseball'] = relationship(back_populates='user_sports', primaryjoin='and_(UserSports.id == Baseball.user_sport_id, UserSports.sport_id.has(sport='baseball'))' 
    
class Baseball(Base):
    __tablename__ = "baseball"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped(column(ForeignKey('users.id', nullable=False)
    position: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    team: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    number: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    user_sports: Mapped['UserSports'] = relationship(back_populates='baseball', foreign_key='user_id')

class Sports(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sports"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    sport: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    user_sports: Mappped[List["UserSports"]] = relationship(back_populates='sports', foreign_key='UserSports.sport_id')

When I run this I get the following error.
Property 'sport_id' is not an instance of ColumnProperty (i.e. does not correspond directly to a Column).
I know I am messing up somewhere with my primaryjoin, but I am not sure how to fix it. I do not want to pass the id from sport_id because I won't know the id. I tried following the docs for help.

You do not seem to have a column called sport?id in Baseball

It would always be the same value if i added it to Baseball so I did not add it.
